# Autocorrelation of convolution integral

Tags: autocorrelation, convolution

Work out the autocorrelation

$r_Y(\tau) = E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]$

with 
$Y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t-u) x(u)$
and
$X$ a WSS, ergodic process

I always get: $h(t)* h(t+\tau) * r_X(\tau)$  (with $*$ convolution)

### My approach

(after multiplication)

$\int h(t-u)  ( \int h(t+\tau -u')r_X(u'-u) \text{d}u' ) \text{d}u$

The inner integral is the definition of a convolution hence
$= \int h(t-u)  ( h(t+\tau)*r_x(t+\tau-u) ) \text{d}u$

This gives again a convolution integral with time variable t. so,

$= h(t)* h(t+\tau) * r_X(\tau) $

### Correct solution:

$  r_X(\tau) * h(\tau) * h(-\tau) $

### Question

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is difficult because the notation doesn't make sense. Presumably, $h=g$. (If not, what is $h$?) Convolution is an operation on *functions* whereas expressions like $h(\tau)$ and $h(-\tau)$ are *numbers.* Thus, for instance, it makes sense to write expressions like $$(h * r_X)(t)=\int_\mathbb{R}h(t-u)r_X(u)du$$ but this is *not* equal to "$h(t)*r_X(t)$," which has no meaning. Because of this confusion, after a good start to the solution things begin to go awry at the second step when "$*$" first appears. If you straighten out this notation you might find the problem is simple.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for clearing this up. So that means that the presented solution is nonsense?

Comment: I'm not sure--it depends on what you really mean by the "$h$" notation.  I'm struggling to make sense of it, but maybe I'm overlooking something that's obvious to you.

Comment: @whuber sorry. I've corrected it (g had to be h)  h is the impulse response of a linear system.

Answer (score 2):

An adapted and enhanced version of 
[an answer of mine on dsp.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/848/235)

Suppose that 
$$\begin{align*}
Y(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(s)X(t-s)\,\mathrm ds \tag{1}
\end{align*}
$$
If we define the crosscorrelation *function* $R_{X,Y}(\tau)$ as 
$$R_{X,Y}(\tau) = E[X(t-\tau)Y(t)],\tag{2}$$ then
$$\begin{align*}
R_{X,Y}(\tau) &= E\left[X(t-\tau)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(s)X(t-s)\,\mathrm ds\right]\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(s)E[X(t-\tau)X(t-s)]\,\mathrm ds\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(s)R_X(\tau-s)\,\mathrm ds.
\end{align*}$$
In short,
$R_{X,Y} = h\star R_X.$
Next, consider 
$$\begin{align}
R_Y(\tau) &= E[Y(t-\tau)Y(t)]\\
&= E\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(s)X(t-\tau-s)\,\mathrm ds \,Y(t)\right]
&{\scriptstyle{\text{substituting from} ~ (1)}}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(s) E[X(t-\tau-s)Y(t)]\,\mathrm ds\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(s) R_{X,Y}(\tau+s)\,\mathrm ds\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde{h}(-s) R_{X,Y}(\tau+s)\,\mathrm ds
&{\scriptstyle{\tilde{h}(t) = h(-t)\ \forall \, t ~\text{is the time-reversed impulse response}}}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde{h}(\lambda) R_{X,Y}(\tau-\lambda)\,\mathrm d\lambda
&{\scriptstyle{\text{substitute}~ \lambda = -s}}
\end{align}$$
that is, $R_Y = \tilde{h}\star R_{X,Y}$, and it follows that 
$$R_Y = \tilde{h}\star h \star R_X = (\tilde{h}\star h)\star R_X = R_h\star R_X$$
where $\tilde{h}(t) = h(-t)$ for all $t$ is the *time-reversed* impulse response
and $R_h = \tilde{h}*h$ is the *autocorrelation* function of the 
*deterministic* signal $h(t)$.  Translated to the frequency domain, this gives the
power spectral density relationship
$$S_Y(f) = |H(f)|^2 S_X(f).$$